# saving the results to a file within a for loop c++

Tags: c++, file, save

I'm doing a lab in university that multiplies out 2 matrices from 2 different files and in one of the questions i've been asked to print the results on the console (which is not a problem, it's already done) but printing it to a new save file is the problem.

i'm fairly new to c++ so i apologize in advance if the mistake is obvious :(

here is my code so far....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ///////// my output file /////////////
    string outfile1, save;

    cout<<"Please enter the name of the file you want to save the results in"<<endl;
    cin>>outfile1;

    ofstream outfile(outfile1.c_str());

    if(!outfile)
    {
        cout<<"Please drag in the right file you want the results to be saved on"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }

    /////// sitting up the first matrix file ////////
    string matrixA;

    cout<< "Please drag file (matrix1) into this window"<<endl;
    cin>>matrixA;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(matrixA.c_str());

    if(!infile)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR: Wrong file, please try restart program and try again."<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string matrix1;

    int a[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<5;j++)
        {
            getline(infile,matrix1,',');
            a[i][j]= stoi(matrix1);
            cout<< a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    infile.close();

    /////// sitting up the 2nd matrix file ////////
    string matrixB;

    cout<< "Please drag file (matrix2) into this window"<<endl;
    cin>>matrixB;

    ifstream infile2;
    infile2.open(matrixB.c_str());

    if(!infile2)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR: Wrong file, please try restart program and try again."<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string matrix2;
    int b[5][5];
    for (int k = 0; k<5;k++)
    {
        for(int l = 0;l<5;l++)
        {
            getline(infile2,matrix2,',');
            b[k][l]= stoi(matrix2);
            cout<< b[k][l]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    infile2.close();

    ////////////// CALCULATIONS //////////////////////
    cout<<"The product of both matrices is: "<<endl;
    int result[5][5];
    while (outfile1)
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {

                result[x][y] = 0;
                for(int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
                {

                    result[x][y] += a[x][z]*b[z][y];
                }

                cout << result[x][y] <<" ";
                outfile1<< result[x][y]<<" "; // <<---------- why can i not do this?
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

is there an easier way to do it? if i try to run the code as it is, it gives me a highlight under the first "<<" saying (no operator "<<" matches these operands)

```
outfile1<<result[x][y]<<" ";
```

Comment: You probably meant `outfile << result[x][y] << " ";`

Comment: It would also be useful to format your code to be more readable (indentation always helps!)

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't compile because of two reasons.

1. `while (outfile1)`

   `outfile1` is an `std::string` (the output file name) and is not convertible to `bool`. It's not quite clear what you tried to achieve with this code.
2. `outfile1<< result[x][y]<<" ";`

   Again, `outfile1` is an `std::string`. Your output stream is `outfile`, so you should change this to

   ```
   outfile << result[x][y] << " ";
   ```

Comment: oh, i was about to try something and forgot to delete it!! totally my bad. and it worked. i was using my logbook from a similar lab i done before but i think i confused myself with having similar names (i'm too lazy)

Answer (score 0):

`outfile1` is of type string, while `outfile` is of type ofstream. Change `outfile1` to be `outfile` on lines 86 and 100 and it should compile as expected.

You may want to name your variables differently to help prevent errors like this, perhaps naming `outfile1` as `outfileName`.